# How to add null value of all column of tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

My database has 60 tables.

Earlier I was using MySQL 5 version where if the column doesn't have null value as default still it can accept a blank value. But in MySQL 8 we have to give the default value as null if we are not inserting any value for the column.

I can alter my table column manually but it will take lots of time.

Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: Sometimes to have so many tables can be indicative of poor design

Comment: Please provide a brief example showing an example of the problem.  Also, please describe how you have moved from MySQL 5 to 8.  (Either of these may help us suggest an alternative that solves your problem.)

Answer (score 0):

You can query the MySQL database to see what are default values for all your columns in the database:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, column_default 
FROM  information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema='<database_name>';
```

Then, from the result set, pick the columns that need to be altered, and write down proper ALTER queries like:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ALTER COLUMN <column_name> SET DEFAULT <default_value>;
```

Comment: It is not that simple.  The rest of the specification for the column (eg, `VARCHAR(123) COLLATE...`) must be repeated in `ALTER TABLE..ALTER COLUMN..`